# Ownerdraw VCL grids not picking expected selected colour for VCL Style

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

Our product uses an owner-draw grid (TStringGrid) - where we are drawing all off the grid. I am trying to make this respect the VCL style that is used by the application. Most of this works, but when i try and get the selected colour for the grid, then it either appears to be black (not great when the style being used is already dark), or a seemingly random gradient. Here is the code I am using to get the selected colour (it maybe that I am using the wrong element or `ElementColor` to get the expected colour).

```
    StyleServices.GetElementColor (StyleServices.GetElementDetails (tgCellSelected), ecFillColor, theColor);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all the `TElementColor` (ecBorderColor, ecFillColor, ecTextColor, ..) are defined for all the possible `TThemedElementDetails`, So you must always check the boolean result returned by the `GetElementColor` function.

If the result is false means which the color is not defined. In your case the there is not a color value defined for the `ecFillColor` when the Element is `tgCellSelected`.

Try this sample, which uses the `tgClassicCellSelected` element instead and if not exist just use the HighLight color of the active VCL Style.

```
if not StyleServices.GetElementColor(StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tgClassicCellSelected), ecFillColor, AColor) then
 AColor := StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clHighlight);
```

Comment: I had experimented with setting it to every type of element, and had settled on the `tgFixedCellNormal` as you suggested. The fall back is a good it as well. Thanks (again)